# Azure - Transfer Blob Storage account to new subscription

Tags: azure

I am attempting to move my storage resource to a new subscription. I have managed to move all of my other resources across, but with this storage resource, I am receiving an error message.

[image]

When I click to see the details, this is the infomration I am given

> ERROR TYPE Resource move validation failed. Please see details. Diagnostic information: timestamp '20161202T110420Z', subscription id
>   '9b0af2c9-172c-480b-a294-7c9e3fe07269', tracking id
>   'ee7f2443-4e5b-4e8c-b335-4f5142585599', request correlation id
>   'c1d9fdd4-f46a-4ccd-990b-f104c40a09ac'. (Code:
>   ResourceMoveProviderValidationFailed)
>
> Error Details
>   Subscription is not registered. (Code:SubscriptionNotRegistered)

I have double checked and the Microsoft.Storage provider is definately registered for that subscription as shown below. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: If Microsoft.Storage is registered on both subscriptions, this issue shouldn't happen. I would suggest you open a ticket with Microsoft so that a dedicated professional will help you with the request.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but for others to reference I found a solution here;

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/f8cc120a-3ca6-4d36-9747-d0c09f6f84cf/unable-to-move-resources-between-subscriptions?forum=windowsazuredata

Basically in the "Service Providers" section of the source subscription ensure you have registered the Microsoft.Compute resource provider, and bingo!